# $PATH precedence not being followed?

Tags: macos, unix

Not entirely sure if this should go here or another stack exchange, but here goes:

see the following output from my shell:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim

$ /opt/local/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jan  9 2013 03:19:25)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-244, 246-762

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 22 2012 15:36:46)
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

As you can see, /opt/local/bin/vim should take precedence over `which vim` as per $PATH definition, however it does not.

Anyone have a clue?

---

In the end, I noticed I had an `export PATH=....` in my .zshrc. So if anybody has the same problem, check for that first ;)

Comment: It could be an `alias` that is getting in the way?

Comment: /etc/paths determines the [order of precedence](http://daniel.hepper.net/blog/2011/02/change-order-of-path-entries-on-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 7):

Did you install `vim` into `/opt/local/bin` during this shell session? Bash (and probably other shells) saves the results of path lookups into a hash table. You can verify this by asking for `type vim`. This is like `which` except it's a builtin that will return results from this hashtable if they exist. More usefully, `type` returns precisely what will be executed by the shell.

You can also use the `hash` builtin to specifically query the saved lookups. Use `hash -t vim` to see what the entry is in the hashtable for `vim`, and use `hash -d vim` to remove `vim` from this hashtable, allowing the shell to look it up in `$PATH` again the next time.

---

I just re-checked your original description and noticed that `which vim` actually returned `/usr/bin/vim`. Since `which` doesn't use the hashtable that I described above, this actually suggests that your problem was different. Perhaps your `$PATH` had some sort of invisible character in the first component?

Comment: Ugh. I forgot that I have my PATH defined in my .zshrc . Thank you for your pointers, I learned something new :)